# Can I somehow update compressed archives?

Tags: shell-script, tar, bzip2

I'm trying to find all files with given extension but I'm getting this error:

```
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
tar: Cannot update compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

Here is the script:

```
touch archive.tar.bz2; find . -type f \( -name '*.bak' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '~*' \) -exec tar rjvf archive.tar.bz2 {} \; -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Is there any way how to update compressed archive using find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't update a compressed archive using `tar`.

**But**, if your script is creating the archive (using `touch`), you can update it and compress it later. Change `rjvf` to `rvf`, and at the end of your script, run `bzip2 archive.tar` (I take it from the `j` option and your tags that you want to use `bzip2` for compression).